# SQL Server Referencing Nested Subqueries

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, subquery

In a sql server database, I am trying to return thegender with the most about of money mad ethrough bonuses. I therefore have a sub query to calculate the sum of bonuses made by each gender, another subquery to return the max and finally, my main query returns the  gender with this max. However my code is not working.

> SELECT E.Gender, maxx.mm
>
> ```
>    FROM HumanResources.Employee as E, 
>    (SELECT MAX(Bonus) as mm 
>     FROM (SELECT E.Gender, SUM(SP.Bonus) AS Bonus 
>           FROM HumanResources.Employee AS E, Sales.SalesPerson AS SP
>           GROUP BY E.Gender) 
>      AS gen) AS  maxx
> ```
>
> where E.Gender = gen.Gender;

The last line :where E.Gender = gen.Gender doesn't seem to work as gen.Gender can't be bound

Any help please

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired results? Also is there a common `EmployeeID` column between `Employee` and `SalesPerson`? Right now you have a bad cross join (two tables but no `WHERE` clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a big fan of the `subquery(subquery(subquery(` model, as it is often wasteful and usually difficult to parse / understand / re-write. Here is how I initially wanted to re-write it when I saw it:

```
SELECT TOP (1) E.Gender, mm = SUM(SP.Bonus)
  FROM Sales.SalesPerson AS sp 
  INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS E
  ON E.EmployeeID = sp.EmployeeID -- guess on relationship
GROUP BY E.Gender
ORDER BY mm DESC;
```

Another way (potentially more efficient depending on the plan, since you will eliminate all but one employee from the join - something that *may* happen above, but also might not):

```
;WITH sp AS
(
  SELECT TOP 1 EmployeeID, mm = SUM(Bonus)
    FROM Sales.SalesPerson
    GROUP BY EmployeeID
    ORDER BY mm DESC
)
SELECT E.Gender, topsp.mm
  FROM sp
  INNER JOIN HumanResources.Employee AS E
  ON E.EmployeeID = sp.EmployeeID; -- again guessing on relationship
```

Comment: I guess someone doesn't like my mohawk.

Answer (score 1):

Put your filter inside the subquery.  You can refer to outer queries from within, so:

```
 AS gen) AS  maxx
```

becomes

```
 AS gen WHERE  E.Gender = gen.Gender) AS  maxx
```

Comment: +1 You'd also have to change the `SELECT` list from `E.Gender` to `maxx.Gender`. But I find the nested-nested subquery model difficult to parse and understand anyway (hence my alternative suggestions :-)).